# Sheaf Theory: When do we have $(\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{G})(U) = \mathscr{F}(U)/\mathscr{G}(U)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I was originally unsure about this in a more basic situation: if I had a quasi-coherent ideal sheaf $\mathscr{I}$ on a scheme $X$ then on an open affine subscheme $U \subset X, U = Spec(A)$ we have $\mathscr{I} |_U = \tilde{\mathfrak{a}}$, an ideal sheaf associated to some ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subset A$. Is it true that $(\mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I})(U) = \mathscr{O}_X(U)/\mathscr{I}(U) = A/\mathfrak{a}$? I have a feeling that since we have an exact sequence 
\begin{equation}
0 \rightarrow \mathscr{I}_x \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{X,x} \rightarrow (\mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I})_x \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
for all $x \in X$ hence for all $x \in U$. So this implies that we have an exact sequence on restriction
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow \mathscr{I}|_U = \tilde{\mathfrak{a}} \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X|_U = \tilde{A} \rightarrow (\mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I})|_U \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{A}$ is the sheaf associated to $A$ viewing as a module over itself. $\mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I}$ is also quasi-coherent since the other two in the exact sequence are, therefore we have $(\mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I})|_U = \tilde{M}$, for a sheaf associated to some $A$-module $M$. But then the exact associated sequence above will implies an exact sequence of $A$-modules
\begin{equation}
0 \rightarrow \mathfrak{a} \rightarrow A \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
meaning $(\mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I})(U) = M = A/\mathfrak{a} = \mathscr{O}_X(U)/\mathscr{I}(U)$. Apparently, because $A_f$ is flat and the argument above should be the same for any quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{G}$ such that $\mathscr{F} \subset \mathscr{G}$ we should also have $(\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{G})(V) = \mathscr{F}(V)/\mathscr{G}(V)$ for any $V\subset X$ that is contained in some affine open subset $U$. Is there any wrong with my reasoning above?

And back to main question: in general when do we have $(\mathscr{F}/\mathscr{G})(U) = \mathscr{F}(U)/\mathscr{G}(U)$?

Comment: On affine scheme, an exact sequence of coherent sheaves gives rise to an exact sequence of sections. This is proven in chapter $II.5$ in Hartshorne. In general, this depends on the first cohomology of $\mathcal G$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So do you think what i wrote about qausi-coherent sheaves was correct?

Comment: Yes, quasi-coherence is sufficient.